# org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not obtain JBoss Transactions transaction manager instance

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I am trying to run hibernate `ogm` for `mongodb`.
I am getting below exception, please can anybody help me fix it?

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not obtain JBoss Transactions   
                                  transaction manager instance.
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I fixed it by adding maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.jbossts</groupId>
    <artifactId>jbossjta</artifactId>
    <version>4.16.4.Final</version>
</dependency>
```